# UITableView cell empty when called recursively

Tags: ios, uitableview, recursion

I'm trying to use recursive table view but when I click to any cell and second UITableView appears (created by tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:), there are just empty rows without any text.

Can somebody help please ?

```
@implementation RSTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        [self.tableView registerClass:[RSCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"bbaCell"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RSTableViewController *rsTableView = [[RSTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    rsTableView.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rsTableView animated:TRUE];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"bbaCell";
    RSCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.label1.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label2.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: You push a new instance of RSTableViewController onto the navigation stack, and set its delegate to the current instance? I cannot imagine how that could work.

Comment: I was missing tableView datasource in  `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, so now it works !

    `rsTableView.tableView.dataSource = self;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** `[self.navigationController pushViewController:rsTableView animated:TRUE]` is wrong, there's no such thing as `TRUE`, there's only `YES`.

**B.** I feel like you're doing something very wrong but anyway, you method should be the following:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    RSTableViewController *rsTableView = [[RSTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // each rs table view instance is it's own delegate and datasource
    rsTableView.tableView.delegate = rsTableView;
    // you forgot to add this line:
     rsTableView.tableView.dataSource = rsTableView;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rsTableView animated:YES];
    // what's this line for ?? the new ViewController will automatically call all the necessary methods. please remove it.
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

please check the syntax, and secondly, what's `RSTableViewController` base ViewController ?? is it `UITableViewController` ??
make sure you're setting the delegate and datasource properly.

Comment: A: In this case TRUE or YES both are usable
B: yes, I was missing tableview datasource
   yes, `[tableView reloadData]` is not necessary

Comment: Yes, UITableViewController is the base class of of RSTableViewController

Thanks for help !

Comment: hmmmm interesting, this is the first time i see TRUE :)

Comment: I've got another problem now: when the new(second and later) tableView is pushed, I get few section headers and in each section I have few rows, but the problem is that labels inside the cells are empty.

Comment: Did you check if the array is populated correctly ??? is `viewDidLoad`  being called on the new table view ?? because that's where the data is generated, that's the only place that would make sense to be the source of the problem